# Should the trademark guidance state that MathOverflow is written in CamelCase, unlike all other sites in the network?

Tags: discussion, bug, legal

Should the [trademark guidance](https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) state that MathOverflow is written in CamelCase, unlike all other sites in the network?

MathOverflow is not a trademark of Stack Exchange, as far as I know. On the other hand, it is a site in the Stack Exchange Network. So, where the trademark guidance states that

> Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.

It actually states an thing that is not true.

Comment: MathOverflow *does* follow the same case convention; is the real question here about the space? i.e. "MathOverflow" vs "Math Overflow"? i.e. the "two words" bit?

Comment: @MarcGravell It is.